# Is there a simple way to create a cascaded function from multiple implementation of same interface in Java?

Tags: java

Is there a simple way to obtain cascaded implementation?

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    void call(SomeClassA a, SomeClassB b, SomeClassC c);
}
```

```
SomeInterface imp1;
SomeInterface imp2;
SomeInterface imp3;

public SomeInterface getFunction() {
    return (a, b, c) -> {
        imp1.call(a, b, c);
        imp2.call(a, b, c);
        imp3.call(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

What I want:

```
public SomeInterface getFunction() {
    return SomeUtils.cascade(imp1, imp2, imp3);
}
```

Is there any `SomeUtils` equivalent?

---

Edited / Added:
More generic way I rewrite this with returning value, it could be like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TriFunction<P1, P2, P3, R> {
    R call(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3);
}
```

```
public class LambdaUtils {
    public static <P1, P2, P3, R> TriFunction<P1, P2, P3, R> cascade(
            BinaryOperator<R> reducer,
            TriFunction<P1, P2, P3, R>... lambdas ) {
        // assumes lambda.length > 0 or should check it
        return (a, b, c) ->
            Arrays.stream(lambdas)
                    .map( l -> l.call(a, b, c) )
                    .reduce( reducer ).get();
    }
}
```

Example of using `LambdaUtils` is like this:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    Object call(Object a, Object b, Object c);
}
```

```
...
    public void hoge() {
        SomeInterface i = (a, b, c) -> a;
        SomeInterface j = (a, b, c) -> b;
        SomeInterface k = (a, b, c) -> c;
        SomeInterface all = LambdaUtils.cascade(
                (a, b) -> (b),
                i::call, j::call, k::call )::call;
    }
...
```

There are several problems with `LambdaUtils.cascade()`:

- This only applies to lambdas with 3 parameters
- This only applies to lambdas with returning R, not void(or if you rewrite above to accept `void` type functions, then it can not be applied to returning result version)

So, can it be rewritten to be:

- Accept any number of parameters
- Does not care returning type(R / void)

Since I think this is kinda universal thing, I am looking for this functionality in some OSS libraries like Apache Commons.

Thanks for your advise!

Comment: Your interface is generic so A,B,C need to be declared as generic type parameters in the definition and specified in the declarations.

Comment: return type can be `Void` to denote no return, impl might still. To be honest, this is a one liner (as shown in my answer), there is no much gain in making it magically generic and accepting all possible combination of return types, arg counts etc .

Comment: This can be done in Typescript, but ther are some magic trics that does not exist in Java like defining a type that describes a signature of given method call (interface), whic is what would be required here.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a cascade here as result of 1 call is not used as an input to the next call. What you have did, can be done with simple for loop or stream

```
public static SomeInterface forEach(SomeInterface... implsArr){
    List<SomeInterface> impls = Arrays.asList(implsArr);
    return (a,b,c)-> impls.forEach(impl->impl.call(a,b,c));
    //or
    return (a,b,c)->{
        for(SomeInterface impl:implsArr){
            impl.call(a,b,c);
        }
    };
}
```

Then it can be used as

```
SomeInterface allInOne=forEach(imp1, imp2, imp3 ... impN);
allInOne.call(a,b,c);
```

Comment: For stream variant basically. I will edit that, thanks

Comment: Should be fine now

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I expanded your answer and edited the question. Is there more generic way to write this utility like accepting arbitral number of parameters? Or does OSS library exists like in commons libraries?